# Why are brake levers still bent in form to accomodate more than one finger?

Tags: brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake, brake-levers

I thought of it for a while now. Our brake levers look like this:

[image]

[image]

Why aren't they designed more like this?

[image]

Is there a purpose for the extra space? Is two-finger braking still essential in hydraulic brakes?

EDIT: Due to the misunderstandings occurring, here's the alternative lever shape I'm talking about.

[image]

Comment: I rarely, if ever, operate my brakes using only one finger.

Comment: What do you expect to gain by shrinking the brake lever?  Some quite small weight and aero savings, but anything else?

Comment: @NuclearWang -- does that apply to hydraulic disc brakes on flat bars?

Comment: @Criggie I did not mention that I'd want the lever length to be shortened. As you can deduce by the pictures I've shown, the 'extra space' I'm talking about is the one closest to the center and inboard of the optimal finger placement.

Comment: OP, I'll quote your question which had 3 sentences before the edit:  `Is two-finger braking still essential in hydraulic brakes?` That's what everyone understood from the question, and what we answered.

Comment: Imagine what the proposed single finger lever will be like wearing gloves or mittens

Comment: @GregoryLeo I'd be tempted to revert that edit so all the answers make sense, and then ask your new question as a new question.  Both are interesting.

Comment: Yeah good question, when you're in the habit of single finger braking, it's hard to imagine going back to something inferior, so why accomodate it? Photo three proves that some designers had the same thought too, so there might be a product on the market. But as your sketch illustrates, the position of the finger you brake with doesn't change... so ergonomically there isn't a great difference... or is there? haven't tried it

Answer (score 9):

TL;DNR - single finger levers have little (if any) advanatage and some disadvantages.

Most people do not start out cycling with XT/Ultegra quality bikes and therefore (do not) start out on bikes that have brakes good enough for one finger control.  Even today, many low end disc brakes cannot reach full braking potential (i.e. wheel lock), with one finger. Also think of kids' bikes and kids' hand/finger strength.  No way an average child with an average child's bike can brake with one finger.

People transitioning from those brakes would likely be uncomfortable with single finger levers during the transition, and would likely not buy a bike equipped with them. If the bike might be resold or lent out, one with single finger levers would have a smaller potential market.

Poor maintenance, accepting pad contamination can occur at any time, means even the very best brakes may require more force than a single finger to achieve full stopping potential.

Presuming the bike has good, well maintained brakes and single finger braking is how the rider rides all the time, what's the disadvantage of current lever designs? They work very well on a single finger.  A rider can intuitively feel exactly where on the lever the finger is to achieve maximum performance. Changing the shape will not improve braking, and there is no weight saving to be made.

The only advantage would be aesthetics and marketing spin to sell the new shape as a premium product aimed at the cashed up MAMILs.

Comment: Made a few edits for clarity, but left "(do not)" in brackets in paragraph 2, because I'm assuming that is what you mean, but can you confirm by editing out the brackets i put in? without "do not" i think the meaning is different. +1 though, this covers all of the reasons I can think of... no advantage, only disadvantage.

Comment: Cashed-up MAMILs!  Ha ha!

Answer (score 3):

A question that starts with "why" will often be hard to answer objectively, but I'd simply say that:

- **about length:** making brake levers too small will make actually catching them in an emergency more difficult, and you don't want that, so they need to be at least a certain length.
- **about leverage:** longer levers have more leverage (naturally) and even for hydraulic brakes, it's still a good thing to require less finger force
- **about shape:** the strongest finger is the middle finger (it accounts for over 1/3 of the hand's grip strength). A good majority of cyclists have a natural tendency to use the index and middle finger because of this. Manufacturers probably design most brake levers around this fact as there is no functional disadvantage for a single finger braker to use those levers whereas the opposite isn't true. The hook shape would handle awkwardly and having all fingers inline is the simplest solution.

Comment: That's almost correct but the important part is the distance to the fulcrum! It doesn't matter how long the lever is as the fulcrum is a fixed position. A 5" lever applies the same force if used with a hand or a single finger. The overall length of a lever is only an advantage if you can move the pivot point.

Comment: @DanK Please correct me if I'm fundamentally wrong, but as far as I know, even with a fixed load/fulcrum distance, a longer force/fulcrum distance increases mechanical advantage thus decreasing force required for the same work.

Comment: I did not say that shaping the lever for one-finger braking would result in shortening its length. I'm just talking about removing that extra 'finger space' towards the fulcrum and just leave the single-finger space at the end.

Comment: @GregoryLeo Did you just downvote my answer to your unclear question in spite? Just so you know, I wasn't the one who downvoted your question, and my answer was perfectly valid to what was in the question before the edit.

Comment: Why does too small make them difficult to catch? Which dimension changed? As for the lever length, it is roughly the same in the third photo in the original question as the first, because with one finger braking you rest it at the end of the lever. Motorcyclists use the whole right hand to brake so how does this compare? As for the sketched edit, how did the lever get further away from the bar? you say fingers plural, but question concerns single finger braking...

Comment: @Swifty 1. Are you really arguing that a smaller lever isn't inherently harder to catch? 2. The lever in the 3rd image is most definitely shorter than the one in the 1st 3. The reason I say fingers plural is because single finger brakers aren't the majority and no manufacturer will disadvantage two finger brakers for the former's sake. There is no functional disadvantage for single finger brakers to have 'classic' levers, but the opposite isn't true. That's a direct answer to OP's `Why aren't they designed more like this?`

Comment: @GabrielC. no... no I wasn't arguing anything, I was asking questions, for clarification. I'm still not arguing, just want to understand the points you're making.I shouldn't have brought up the length comparison, because there is no objective comparison atm. OP clarified that length is not part of the question, so doesn't need to be in the answer. I think your answer in that comment is actually much better than the actual answer.

Comment: @GregoryLeo *I'm just talking about removing that extra 'finger space' towards the fulcrum and just leave the single-finger space at the end.* What's the point?  That would make the lever no easier to operate with a single finger while making it harder to operate with more than one finger should the cyclist want to do that.

Comment: @Swifty Super. I'll update my answer with those ideas in mind.